# Implementing Trie using java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, trie

Tried to implement trie but it shows memory Limit exceeded.
The operations I tried to preform are insert Search and starts With 
and to implement these functions I have created util functions for it.
I tried to submit this solution in leetcode but is shoes memory Limit EXCEEDED .
Kindly look into this code and help me to understand the problem and also in many program I have seen they keep count variable what is the purpose for that.

```
class Trie {

    /** Initialize your data structure here. */
   Trie root;
    Trie []links;
    final int r=26;

    public boolean isEnd;

    public Trie() {

          links=new Trie[r];
        root=new Trie();
    }
    public boolean containsKey(char c)
    {
        return links[c-'a']!=null;
    }
    public Trie get(char ch)
    {
        return links[ch-'a'];
    }
    public void put(char ch,Trie node)
    {
        links[ch-'a']=node;
    }
    public void setEnd()
    {
        isEnd=true;
    }
    public boolean isEnd()
    {
        return isEnd;
    }

    /** Inserts a word into the trie. */
    public void insert(String word) {
        Trie node=root;
        for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
        {
            char ch=word.charAt(i);
            if(!node.containsKey(ch))
            {
                node.put(ch,new Trie());
            }
            node=node.get(ch);
        }
        node.setEnd();   
    }

    /** Returns if the word is in the trie. */
    public boolean search(String word) {           
        Trie node=searchPrefix(word);
      //    Trie node=null;
        return node!=null && node.isEnd();
    }
    public Trie searchPrefix(String word)
    {
        Trie node=root;
        for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
        {
            char ch=word.charAt(i);
            if(node.containsKey(ch))
            {
                node=node.get(ch);
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
        return node;
    }

    /** Returns if there is any word in the trie that starts with the given prefix. */
    public boolean startsWith(String prefix) {
       Trie node=searchPrefix(prefix);
        //Trie node=null;
        return node!=null;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate cause of your OutOfMemory error is that you have a recursion in the constructor of your `Trie`:

```
public Trie() {
    links=new Trie[r];
    root=new Trie();
}
```

Do you see that to create a `Trie` you have to create a `Trie`. This is going to continue until you run out of memory.

That said, I think you actually need to restructure your code slightly, breaking out the existing functionality into two separate classes:  a `Trie` - the structure as a whole - and a `TrieNode` - which contains references to child `TrieNode`s. The `Trie` will contain a reference to a root `TrieNode`.

The `TrieNode` class:

```
class TrieNode
{
    /** Initialize your data structure here. */
    TrieNode[] links;
    final int r = 26;

    public boolean isEnd;

    public TrieNode()
    {
        links = new TrieNode[r];
    }

    public boolean containsKey(char c)
    {
        return links[c - 'a'] != null;
    }

    public TrieNode get(char ch)
    {
        return links[ch - 'a'];
    }

    public void put(char ch, TrieNode node)
    {
        links[ch - 'a'] = node;
    }

    public void setEnd()
    {
        isEnd = true;
    }

    public boolean isEnd()
    {
        return isEnd;
    }
}
```

And the `Trie` class:

```
class Trie
{
    TrieNode root;

    public Trie()
    {
        root = new TrieNode();
    }

    /** Inserts a word into the trie. */
    public void insert(String word)
    {
        TrieNode node = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            char ch = word.charAt(i);
            if (!node.containsKey(ch))
            {
                node.put(ch, new TrieNode());
            }
            node = node.get(ch);
        }
        node.setEnd();
    }

    /** Returns if the word is in the trie. */
    public boolean search(String word)
    {
        TrieNode node = searchPrefix(word);
        // Trie node=null;
        return node != null && node.isEnd();
    }

    public TrieNode searchPrefix(String word)
    {
        TrieNode node = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            char ch = word.charAt(i);
            if (node.containsKey(ch))
            {
                node = node.get(ch);
            } else
                return null;
        }
        return node;
    }

    /**
     * Returns if there is any word in the trie that starts with the given prefix.
     */
    public boolean startsWith(String prefix)
    {
        TrieNode node = searchPrefix(prefix);
        // Trie node=null;
        return node != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped. Can you tell me more about why some counting variable is used in implementing trie in some programs?

Comment: @Vortex If you keep a count of how many times each node is reached when inserting a word in the trie you can quickly tell how many words start with the prefix represented by each node. The count on the root node would tell you how many words are in the trie.